# How to profile cython code called by another python script?

Tags: cython

```
$ cat calc_pi.pyx
# cython: profile=True
# cython: language_level=3
# cython linetrace=True

# calc_pi.pyx

cimport cython

@cython.profile(False)
def recip_square(int i):
    return 1. / i ** 2

def approx_pi(int n=10000000):
    cdef double val = 0.
    cdef int k
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        val += recip_square(k)
    return (6 * val) ** .5

$ cat runme.py
import calc_pi
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='{0}'.format(__file__))
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--index", help="specify number", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    num = int(args.index)
    print(calc_pi.approx_pi(num))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Question> I have seen how to profile individual cython function such as `calc_pi.approx_pi`. However I have problems to profile these functions through a calling python script.

For example, assume that you cannot directly profile the function `calc_pi.approx_pi` because you need some parameters/pre-processing from the python script(i.e. `runme.py`).

Is there a way that I can profile the `calc_pi.approx_pi` through the calling of `runme.py`?

Thank you

Comment: Profile Cython functions directly(http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html#profiling-tutorial)

Comment: I haven't actually used Cython profiling, but have you tried the standard `python -m cProfile runme.py --arguments --more-arguments --something=1`?

Comment: @DavidW, I had tried cProfile before. It only generates profiling for all functions defined inside the .py. No functions within pyx are shown in the results.

Comment: If I copy your example, compile it with `cythonize-3.6 -i calc_pi.pyx`, and then run it with `python3 -m cProfile runme.py -i50000000` I get an output which includes `approx_pi` (taking the majority of the runtime). Unfortunately, if that doesn't work for you I don't have a lot of ideas why...

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question, but I came across the same problem so I thought it might be useful to post what worked for me.

Begin your Cython script with: `# cython: profile=True` (as you have already done) and in your **Python** script, `import cProfile` and then `cProfile.run('cython_function(arguments)').`